# Ajax запрос при закрытии страницы

Tags: jquery, ajax, php

Есть страничка Х.
Нужно при закрытии или переходе на другую страницу выполнить запрос в бд.
Делаю так:
скрипт на jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.onunload = function() {
        var post_id = $('span.id');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "date_end.php",
            data: "number_id=post_id.data('number-id')&event_id=post_id.data('event-id')"
            }
        });
    }
});
```

а потом сам скрипт на php:

```
$number_id = $_POST['number_id'];
$event_id = $_POST['event_id'];

$query = "UPDATE `phone` SET `status` = 0 WHERE `id` = $number_id";
$stmt  = $db->exec($query);

$query2 = "UPDATE `event` SET `date_end` = NOW() WHERE `id` = $event_id";
$stmt2  = $db->exec($query2);
```

но что-то походу не так..не срабатывает почему то...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проблема была в параметре data, нужно так:

```
data: "number_id="+post_id.data('number-id')+"&event_id="+post_id.data('event-id')
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте посмотреть в консоли отладки (Ctrl+Shift+I), вероятно данные не приходят на сервер

А вообще для отправки форм AJAXом используйте

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: url,
       data: $("#idForm").serialize(),
       success: function(data)
       {
           alert(data);
       }
     });
```